# Callable and closures

Tags: php, lambda, closures

I've created not very complex test code (tested in PHP 5.5.12):

```
<?php

class Test
{
    private $cached = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cached = [];
        $this->cached[0] = 12;
    }

    function wrap($function, $index)
    {
        if (isset($this->cached[$index])) {
            return $this->cached[$index];
        }

        $result = call_user_func($function);

        return $result;
    }
}

class B
{
    public function run()
    {
        $x = 6;
        $obj = new Test();
        $value = $obj->wrap(
            function () use ($x) {
                return $this->test($x);
            },
            1
        );
        echo $value."<br />";
    }


    protected function test($x)
    {
        echo "I'm running ";
        return $x * $x;
    }
}

class C extends B
{
    public function run()
    {
        $x = 6;
        $obj = new Test();

        $myFunc = function () use ($x) {
        return $this->test($x);
        };

        $value = $obj->wrap($myFunc, 1);
        echo $value."<br />";
    }
}

class D extends B
{
    public function run()
    {
        $x = 6;
        $obj = new Test();

        $value = $obj->wrap(array($this, 'test'), 1);
        echo $value."<br />";
    }
}


$b = new B();
$b->run();

$c = new C();
$c->run();

$d = new D();
$d->run();
```

Probably there are some parts of the code you could say it could be done better but the main point are closures function and callable. Those classes simulate in a very simple way caching system. If data is in cache it returns data from cache otherwise function that gets data is called (of course this cache system doesn't work because it doesn't have to - it's just a sample code).

Questions:

1) Why when using object `$d` I get the following warning:

```
call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, cannot access protected method D::test()
```

and is it possible to launch protected method from parent? When I change this method from protected to public it can be launched without a problem

2) As you probably noticed I want to use some arguments for function I call using `call_user_sync`. Unfortunately I don't know those parameters when I call `call_user_func` so in class B and C I used closures where I can use/pass extra parameters. I have 2 extra questions connected to this:

- is it the way where closures are useful and commonly used?
- is it possible using object `$d` to pass parameters to test method without using closures but not when calling `call_user_sync` but inside class `D`?

Comment: _is it possible to launch protected method from parent?_ This is not the thing you're doing. You don't launch protected method from parent. You're trying to call protected method of `Test` instance inside method of `D` instance.

Comment: Are you sure? In my code I see I'm trying to call protected method `test` of `B` class (that is parent to `D` class) and when I change this method to public this method is being launched

Comment: You can use `array($this, 'method')` with private/protected methods only when used in same context. When you create object `$obj` inside function and pass callback `array($this, 'test')` to this object function, it is passed without context. Inside `Test::wrap` function, callback is called as `$objectOfClassD->test(1)`, not `$this->test(1)` and method `D::test()` is protected. When you make `D::test()` public it is accessible from any context and no warning is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to note scope at the time of the execution.  You are *creating* the callback in the correct scope, but you are *executing* the callback in another object with no access to the `protected` method (the callback get's executed in `class Test` not in a parent or child of `class B`.

I ran in to this issue some time ago when writing my own dispatcher class.  One option was to set a "parent" on the dispatcher, and pass the dispatcher as one of the parameters on the callback.  The callback then checks the "parent" associated with the Dispatcher for `=== $this`, and then knows that it has access and goes to town.

You have to do your own access checking, is the point.